# Is there any reward for completing rdr 2 missions with gold medal?

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

I have noticed after the first chapter of RDR 2, there are medals awarded for completing the side objectives in the missions. 
From what I have read you earn an achievement if you get at least 70 gold medals.

Is there anything more to this mechanic? Do you get a special reward beside achievement? Does it contribute to the 100% completion to aim for the gold medals?

Was not able to find any info regarding this one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[The only information I could find](https://www.powerpyx.com/red-dead-redemption-2-gold-medals-guide/) on gold medals stated that the only reward for them is the 70 gold medal achievement. They're not relevant to [100%ing the game](https://www.powerpyx.com/red-dead-redemption-2-100-guide-checklist/), as that only requires completion of the main story.